# To delete a desk top file in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io

i want a solution for this , i want to delete a file which is residing in my desk top using asp.net c# , i used below code:

```
try 
{
    FileInfo TheFile = new FileInfo(MapPath(".") + "\\" + FileNameTextBox.Text);

    if (TheFile.Exists)
    {
        File.Delete(MapPath(".") + "\\" + FileNameTextBox.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    lblStatus.Text += ex.Message;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblStatus.Text += ex.Message;
}
```

but it always says the file location cannot be found , please help me 
thanks in advance `

Comment: Have you checked that its getting the correct filename and path?

Comment: Where does `MapPath(".")` link to?

Comment: You're talking about deleting a file on the server's desktop, right? Just making sure...

Comment: Why even use the server users desktop to save files on, it doesn't seem like the ideal location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try doing it this way instead:

```
    string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    File.Delete(Path.Combine(desktopPath, "filetobedeleted"));
```

Comment: But as Ozgur states, this will only work in normal c# not ASP.Net

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to delete a user's desktop file using an asp .net page you cannot do it. The code executes on the server side and the path will access to the desktop of the server that your application is being hosted.

Comment: More importantly, to the desktop on the server *of the user that the server is running as*. Most likely you've never seen this and probably can't (the account shouldn't allow interactive logins)